# Old Indian movie where the star has a dog helping him

Tags: identify-this-movie

Its in the 80s most likely. I was a kid and I watched this movie with my father so I do not remember much other than remembering that I loved that movie.

The movie is a typical Bollywood Film about a good guy who fights bad guys with the help of his dog. I remember the last scene where the bad guy was killed (by the dog?) next to a beach. That's all I remember (its been more than 20 years).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The movie may be [Teri Meherbaniyan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teri_Meherbaniyan)

[image]

Where Jackie Shroff is the main lead and he gets killed around the middle of the movie and then the movie takes a 180 degree angle change. His Dog turns out to be the real hero of the movie and kills all the bad people. And the Dog is even only one who knows killers' faces.